# What does "the system of griping fostered in armies" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading Paul Goodman texts and saw the next sentence,

> The system of griping fostered in armies as a means of maintaining childish dependency and avoiding mutiny.
>
> "Designing Pacifist Films", Paul Goodman, 1961

The text is written in 60s. What does the whole sentence mean?

Comment: To be a candidate for reopening, this question must first be edited to present the poster's previous research and an explanation of why that research did not answer their question. They should include in their edit their own theory for what it means and tell exactly where their confusion lies. Questions that are nothing more than "What does all this mean?" are unsuitable for our site as written. They are unlikely to help future visitors to our site.

Answer (score 1):

The surrounding text is written in an imperative mood as instructions. As a standalone sentence, the quote can be written as:

> Explain the system of griping which is fostered in armies as a means of maintaining childish dependency and avoiding mutiny.

"[*Griping*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/griping)" means to complain. See also [this article](https://www.angtec.ang.af.mil/News/Commentaries/Display/Article/454030/how-to-gripe/) discussing it from a military point of view.

> When frustration bubbles up, we may feel the need to vent. Sometimes this venting is called, **griping**.

To "[*foster*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-german/foster)" means

> to encourage or give help to (ideas etc)

The sentence thus tells the reader to explain the system of venting supported in armies with the aim of enforcing a hierarchy and to act as a release of emotions when people have complaints so that nothing builds up over time into mutiny.